# 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:10652' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)

Tags: python, mysql

This may seem trivial to some of you but I'm fairly new to live hosted MySQL databases, so I'm trying to have my python app to connect remotely to a cloud database hosted with cloudcluster.com. After a bit of work, I was able to connect remotely to the database using the terminal and the following command

```
C:\Windows\system32>mysql -h mysql-10652-0.cloudclusters.net -P 10652 -u <Userrname> -p <database>
```

And I got the result.

```
Enter password: ************
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 740
Server version: 5.7.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Then ran this python code, after using pip install to install python connector for MySQL.

```
import pymysql
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

# Fields = the host, the user, the password, the database

try:
    db = mysql.connector.connect(host="127.0.0.1" ,user="<Username>", password="***********" , database="<database>", port="10652")
  
    cursor = db.cursor()

     
    # Creating tables for our data base
    user_table = """CREATE TABLE user(  
                id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
                First_Name VARCHAR(100),
                Last_Name VARCHAR(100),
                Email VARCHAR(100),
                Password VARCHAR(100),
                register_date DATETIME,
                PRIMARY KEY(id));"""

    # Execute databse insertion
    cursor.execute(user_table)
    print("Succesfully created the table")
    
    db.commit()
  
    db.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to create table: ", str(e))
```

And I got the error.

```
2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:10652' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)
```

How is it possible that the same physical machine can be connected and also be denied connection at the very same time?

Comment: The hosts in the 2 attempts at connection are different. The python script is trying to connect to a database on the local machine i.e. your computer.

Comment: Try `host="mysql-10652-0.cloudclusters.net"`